# Q: Amazon API / Bottlenose / MaxQPS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, bottlenose

I am using [bottlenose](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose) to access the Amazon Product API.
As the author is recommending I am throttling the requests with MaxQPS=0.9.

It seems to have no effect. I still get 503 errors after some requests. When changing to `MaxQPS=0.1` (which should work for sure), there is no change at all.

My lines looks like:

```
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(
    amazon_access_key,
    amazon_secret_key,
    amazon_assoc_key,
    Region=amazon_region_id,
    MaxQPS=0.9
)
response = amazon.ItemSearch( .... blah ...)
```

Anybody has a clue?